# How to set bean using java config in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have below details in spring xml file. Now I want to convert it into spring java config bean.

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="test" />
        <property name="port" value="111" />
        <property name="username" value="test@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="test123" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="utilityObject" class="com.ezone.utility.TestUtility">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    </bean>
```

Converted mailSender this bean as below. But How to convert utilityObject in java config spring bean. I am new in this.

```
@Bean(name="mailSender",autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME)
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailConfiguration(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl mail = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mail.setHost("test");
        mail.setPort(111);
        mail.setUsername("test@gmail.com");
        mail.setPassword("test123");

        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        mail.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
        return mail;
    }
```

How can I define below bean :

```
<bean id="utilityObject" class="com.ezone.utility.TestUtility">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
```

The above bean has the reference of `mailSender`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either put a parameter on the `@Bean` method, which will get injected:

```
@Bean
public TestUtility utilityObject(JavaMailSender mailConfiguration) {
    return new TestUtility(mailConfiguration);
}
```

or call from one `@Bean` method in an `@Configuration` to another; Spring will proxy them and make sure the singleton behavior gets applied:

```
@Bean
public TestUtility utilityObject() {
    return new TestUtility(mailConfiguration());
}
```

I think the first one is a bit less magic, but either approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [@configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) for the `JavaMailSenderImpl` class

Refer : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

---

EDIT

```
@Bean
public TestUtility getUtilityObject() {
    return new TestUtility(mailConfiguration());
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your ans. I also need to reference in UtilityObject. How do I do?

Comment: I couldn't get this part `I also need to reference in UtilityObject.` please add more details in the question

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty - Please see the Edit Section

Answer (score 0):

The methods annotated with @Bean can be called from other methods. Spring makes proxy for @Configuration class and singletons are created only once.

```
@Bean
public TestUtility utilityObject() {
    TestUtility uo = new TestUtility();
    uo.setMailSender(mailConfiguration());
    return uo;
}
```

See details http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config